# Angular Library Module generate a component from workspace

Tags: angular, module, angular-components, angular-module, angular-library

I have an Angular Workspace created with three projects. As well as I have just created a Library that I would like to have reusable modules inside.

Typically for the projects (applications and library) I run the following to generate a module or component:

`ng g c component componentName --project=UserPortal`

`ng g c component componentName --project=myLibrary`

However now I need to add components to the modules inside them:

**For example the Library:**
    projects
      myLibrary
        src 
          lib
            navigation-module
              *Add Component here*

**For Application Project Module:**
    projects
      UserPortal
        src
          app
            userModule
              *Add Component Here*

I was able to create a module inside the Library project from the Workspace by running:

`ng generate module navigation-module --project=myLibrary`

Currently I have to go through command line down to that directory just to create a component. But I have a feeling I can do this from the **Workspace** like all the other commands. This would be most beneficial instead of either having to command lines up or going back and forth between directories.

Quick overview:

1. Have a Library created within an Angular Workspace
2. Created a module inside the Library within the Angular Workspace
3. Want to create a component inside the module within the Library from the Workspace

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can create components for feature modules by providing the correct path. In your case

```
ng g c navigation-module/test-component --project=myLibrary
```

should do the trick.

Comment: what about making the component to be included in the module declaration?

Comment: @ciekawy: the modules declarations should be updated automatically. In my example in the `navigation-module.module.ts` file `TestComponentComponent` would be added in the declarations-array.

Comment: Thanks! I found that as well. I think there is feature request for an option to update module file - after all schematics should make a dev life easier ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your custom directory path along with `ng` command.

`ng g c myfolder\mycomponent`

But there are chances that you miss spell the path and either new folder gets created or target directory changes. For this reason `dryRun` is very helpful. It displays an output of how the changes is going to be affected.
[image]

After verifying the result you can run the same command without `-d` to make the changes.

> --dryRun=true|false
>
> When true, runs through and reports activity without writing out results.
>
> Default: false
>
> Aliases: -d

Official Doc :- https://angular.io/cli/generate